# Is there a way that we can report a Bitcoin scam?

Tags: mining-pools, fraud

Good day

Is there a way that we can report a Bitcoin scam? I was recently scammed over R200000 therefore I would like to report the person and the platform to alert people of her fraudulent platform.

Answer (score 1):

The primary way to report scams is to contact your local police.

Since Bitcoin is a peer to peer payment system, there is no hierarchy of control, no Bitcoin central authority to whom you can report scams or who can act or coordinate actions against scammers.

There are some social media and other websites that collect lists of scams, so you could report your problem to those. For example, search for [bitcoin scam blacklist](https://www.google.com/search?q=bitcoin+scam+blacklist). I doubt that this is very effective though. It might alert a few of the more diligent people but many people who fall for scams don't seem to have done much research of this sort beforehand.

Scams that exploit weaknesses in, for example, wallet implementations can be reported to the developers of the software concerned (see recent phishing attack on [Electrum](https://electrum.org/#home) by malicious servers issuing false update warning dialogues).

I don't know of scams that exploit weaknesses in the underlying network protocols - but those tend to get noticed by developers and result in [Bitcoin Improvement Proposals (BIPs)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Improvement_Proposals).

> People wishing to submit BIPs, first should propose their idea or document to the bitcoin-dev@lists.linuxfoundation.org mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

Depend on your context so if you got scammed when you send them the money and they didn't send u the bitcoin then yes, this can be reported or chargeback as money are government controlled.

If your dealing with the cryptocurrency transaction for a good (aka send bitcoin for something) then this cannot be recoverable as bitcoin is a one-way transaction. Even if this is reported, your coin will still loose since bitcoin is mostly (not completely) anonymous way of sending/receiving money (Another reason why hackers/scammer uses bitcoin).